# Cocos2d-x keyboard event key codes not working

Tags: lua, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to set up a keyboard event listener using Cocos2d-x in lua. I've got the events firing and the callbacks working, but the keycodes I'm getting do not match the constants in the cc.KeyCode module.

Here's the relevant code:

```lua
local function onKeyPressed(keyCode, event)
    local _, y = sp:getPosition() -- Get the sprite's position
    if keyCode == cc.KeyCode.KEY_SPACE then
        y = y + 20
        sp:setPositionY(y)
    end
end

local klistener = cc.EventListenerKeyboard:create()
klistener:registerScriptHandler(onKeyPressed, cc.Handler.EVENT_KEYBOARD_PRESSED)
eventDispatcher:addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(klistener, layerForeground)
```

When I print the keyCode and cc.KeyCode.KEY_SPACE constant after pressing spacebar, the two values do not match at all. I get a keyCode of 59, and the constant is 56. I've tried various other keys, and so far Tab seems to be the only one where the two values match.

Furthermore, I've looked at [this site](http://www.w3.org/2002/09/tests/keys.html) to check the codes my keyboard is sending, and the keycodes the site gives match neither the reported keyCode nor the constants in the KeyCode module.

Comment: what operating system are you on?

Comment: I'm doing this on Windows 7